# Why my function in connectedCallback is called twice and not following the order

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events

I am still in journey to understand on how LWC works . I read some doc and try to do poc , so i am really apologize if my question is not proper to be asked. Feel free to devote it =)

Note : Component A and B is different components and does not have any relationship except they can be combined in the Lightning record page.

Component A that fire event

```
  connectedCallback() {
    this.getDetails();
  }

  getDetails() {
    getDetails({
      accountId: this.recordId,
    }).then((result) => {
      this.error = undefined;
      JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
      this.isFlag = result.isFlag;
      this.eventData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
      if (this.isFlag) {
        this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
        fireEvent(this.pageRef, "MyEvent", this.eventData);
      } else {
        fireEvent(this.pageRef, "MyEvent", this.eventData);
      }
    });
  }
```

Component B that listen to the event.
 As I understand that i am not able to control the listener , so I try to perform function in connectedcallback. However when I trouble shoot the sequence of function that being performed is not in order. It perform (2) then it call (1) , so in this case (1) is overwritten by (2). Is there anyway to have control on this?

```
  connectedCallback() {
    this.handleEveryItem(); //(1) I run this just in case there is no event to listen

    //(2) then register listener . Handle data is basically call method (1) so it will based on event.
    registerListener("MyEvent", this.handleData, this);
  } //end of connectedCallback

  handleData(eventData) {
    this.isFlag = eventData.isFlag;

    if (this.isFlag && eventData.parentId === this.recordId) {
      this.listAccountId = eventData.listAccountId;
      this.handleEveryItem();
    } else {
      this.listAccountId = [this.recordId];
      this.handleEveryItem();
    }
  }

  handleEveryItem() {
    retrieveList({
      listAccountId:
        this.listAccountId.length === 0 ? [this.recordId] : this.listAccountId,
    }).then((result) => {
      this.error = undefined;
      this.taskResults = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)).map((record) => {
        record.AssignedTo = record.Owner.Name;
        record.taskUrl = "/" + record.Id;
        return record;
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Without seeing handleEveryItem and handleData, there's no way we could figure out why things are going the way they are. Does (1) call something asynchronously? What is it doing? Where is MyEvent coming from? When you do expect to get it, if at all? Without seeing more code, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: thank you for quick reply , I have updated my question . Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. If (1) happens before (2), how is (2) being overwritten by (1)?

Comment: when check the console log : handleEveryItem is run twice however the one that called by listener run first  registerListener("MyEvent", this.handleData, this); because based on this ,the record return two row . And it run again which is return only one data that should handled before listener is registered.My goal if there is listener , the listener should overwritten the previous   this.handleEveryItem() .